# mongodb: better to store as attribute or create association?

Tags: mongodb, associations, nosql

For attributes on a document that are frequently used to search by, would it be better to store as an association instead?

for example, say we have many 'posts', and each post has a category as an attribute.

however we know that we are often going to filter by categories (eg. find all posts with Category A)

in such cases, would it be better to create a separate collection for 'categories', and have them reference posts?

Comment: huh? you mean posts reference categories, right?

Comment: I was thinking of having a collection of categories, and for each category store a list of post IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongodb usual better to avoid associations whenever it possible ([embedded](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference) documents) because with relations everything will work slower. But in case of category and post you can create two separate collections posts, categories. And when you need need to search by category you will load category id from categories collection by category name and then search by category id within posts collection.

Comment: great, thank you.

in this case, is there a performance difference if I search by category name rather than id?

Comment: In the posts collection create an index on category or a compound index like category+post_date if you use complex queries.